# Binary tree, cannot free memory

Tags: c, malloc, binary-search-tree, free, allocation

I've made a binary tree (BST) and it works just fine, but I can't free my allocated memory. The nodes are made of pointers (left, right, parent) and data, which is first name, name and phone number. First name and name are static char arrays, and phone number is of int and it's also a key for my tree. I use this function to free the memory:

```
void FreeYourTree(node* x)
{
    if (!x)
        return;
    FreeYourTree(x->left);
    FreeYourTree(x->right);
    free(x);
    x = NULL;
}
```

But when I use that function and then show my tree inOrder it still shows records but sometimes with some trash chars instead of first name. I really can't find what's wrong with that. I also give You my insert function:

```
void insert(node** root)
{
    node* x = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        printf("Malloc error");
        return;
    }
    printf("put first name: ");
    scanf("%s", x->f_name);
    printf("put name: ");
    scanf("%s", x->s_name);
    printf("put number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &(x->number));
    x->left = NULL;
    x->right = NULL;
    x->parent = NULL;

    node* a = NULL;
    node* walk = *root;
    while (walk != NULL)
    {
        a = walk;
        if (x->number < walk->number)
        {
            walk = walk->left;
        } else {
            walk = walk->right;
        }
    }
    x->parent = a;
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        *root = x;
        return;
    }
    if (x->number < a->number)
    {
        a->left = x;
    } else {
        a->right = x;
    }
}
```

Everything else works fine - showing inorder, showing max and min (everything recurrent), searching, counting nodes and tree height, so it looks like free(x) is really freeing static first name char array, which is actually first variable in struct definition. Here is my structure:

```
typedef struct wezel {
    char f_name[SIZE];
    char s_name[SIZE];
    long int number;
    struct wezel* left;
    struct wezel* right;
    struct wezel* parent;
} node;
```

SIZE is defined as 64.
Thank You for Your help, I'm really stuck :(

Comment: Why are you printing the tree after you free it?

Comment: `FreeYourTree()` seems to be OK, it just contains an unnecessary `x = NULL;`.

Comment: @zuroslav x = NULL is a good thing you did to avoid dangling pointers.

Comment: @zuroslav Now,it will work.

Comment: @zuroslav Now,if you try to print a node's data after freeing its memory,a segmentation fault will be generated.

Comment: the `x = NULL;` at the end of `FreeYourTree` has no effect since x is just a local copy of the argument. Basically after you freed your tree you still have pointers pointing all over the place into freed memory.

Comment: Calling `free()` on memory marks it as unused, it does not actually overwrite the content.

Comment: Okay thank You all very much. I'm printing the tree after freeing it to ensure it will show "no records", so I can add new records from the beginnng. That's why I wanted to null those nodes and not only free them. I changed my function to take `node** x` instead of `node* x` and modified it for that purpose and it works now well. Thanks